# Comma after "that if"

Tags: commas

> You need not fear that I will not take every care of myself, for I
> love you too much to do anything which would injure my health for I
> know that if I were to do so it would make you miserable.

Is there a missing comma after "If I were to do so"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When a restrictive adverbial clause (in this case, "if I were to do so") appears at the beginning of another clause (in this case, "that if I were to do so it would make you miserable"), a comma after the adverbial clause is optional. You can find a very recent discussion of this issue here: https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/579843/usually-when-a-dependent-clause-precedes-an-independent-clause-a-comma-should/579886

On a separate note, I do not like the fact that this sentence has three main clauses all separated by "for". I would recommend breaking it up, e.g.:

> You need not fear that I will not take every care of myself, for I love you too much to do anything which would injure my health. I know that if I were to do so[,] it would make you miserable.

Comment: It's a quote from a book. "My hand will write what my heart dictates", by Frances Porter, Charlotte Macdonald, and Tui Macdonald.

Comment: I agree. That sentence is a mess.